# Rails + Nokogiri : controller create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am creating a simple_form that allows users to create a new article in my database by providing a link to the original article. If the user provides a URL ("original_url"), I will use Nokogiri to fetch the information.

I get the following error message: "no implicit conversion of nil into String", which tells me that the simple_form input from the field "original_url" is not available to be used in the controller / Nokogiri.

Is it possible to use a variable from a simple_form before saving it?

My controller - create code:

```
def create
  if @original_url = nil
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
  else
    @url = params[:original_url] #### I think this is where the problem is. How do I pass the "original_url" input into the controller? ####
    data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
    headline = data.at_css(".entry-title").text.strip
    @article = Article.new(:headline => headline)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Should I call the "original_url" variable in another way?

Comment: It seems `params[:original_url]` does not contains any value

Comment: will you please provide your `form` code for `original_url` param?

Comment: "I will use Nokogiri to fetch the information." It's important to understand Nokogiri doesn't "fetch" anything. It only parses and allows you to search/extract/change/mangle. How you retrieve the data is what fetches, and most often we use OpenURI, which provides the ability to open a URL using `open`, or another HTTP client.

Comment: Thx for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you use an assignment in the first condition:

```
if @original_url = nil
```

So `@original_url` always becomes `nil` and the condition is never true. That's a classic mistake.

That's how you check for `nil` in Ruby:

```
if @original_url.nil?
```

Now, the reason why `@url` is nil is most likely that in your params, you have `article` root. In this case, you need to write:

```
@url = params[:acticle][:original_url]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now :-)

For future reference, I had to use "if @url.empty?" and not "if @original_url.nil?".

If you have the time Ilya, could you perhaps share a link to the rails documentation that explains how params[:model][:column] works? It was really difficult to find any documentation, as I had no idea what words to use :-)

Again, thx a lot for the help!

Comment: You're welcome :) Take a look at the [Parameters section of the official Rails guide on controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) to learn about the possibilities there. Rails Guides are a good start to learn about most Rails topics.